# Iterative solvers for problems in solid and structural mechanics

Tags: finite-element, sparse-matrix, preconditioning, solid-mechanics, krylov-method

I am looking for comprehensive literature (papers, books, reports etc..) on iterative solvers for solid and structural mechanics problems to understand the best iterative solvers and preconditioners for general problems consisting of anisotropic and unstructured meshes with elements with large aspect ratios and multi-point constraints.

Comment: So a poorly conditioned indefinite system; sounds like just about the worst possible case for iterative solvers :)  Multigrid methods (which can be a bit more of a hassle) should be strong as always I would think.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what makes the problem indefinite?

Comment: Hm, well I guess I was sloppy. If the constraints are enforced with Lagrange multipliers the system would at best be positive semidefinite, and typically causing trouble for iterative solvers.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman, yeah, welcome to reality :) Most academic libraries which scale to 10000s of processors use a friendly isotropic mesh, single material, no contacts, no constraints, making them useless for practical problems.

Comment: Ah my bad, I missed that there were constraints. This can at least lead to saddle-point problems which are a pain